# react native reanimated 2 rotate calculation

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have a calculation and want put that into a useMemo hook. But it does not work and I get no errors.

```
const SIZE = 100.0;

const App = () => {

  const progress = useSharedValue(1);

  const scale = useSharedValue(2);

  const [reset, setReset] = useState(false);

  const reanimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      opacity: progress.value,
      borderRadius: (progress.value * SIZE) / 2,
      transform: [{ scale: scale.value }, { rotate: calculate}]
    }
  }, [progress, scale]);

  const makeAn = () => {

      progress.value = withRepeat(withTiming(0.5), -1, true);
      scale.value = withRepeat(withSpring(1), -1, true);
    
  };

  const calculate = useMemo(() => {
    return `${progress.value * 2 * Math.PI}rad`;
  }, [makeAn, progress, scale]);
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put 'worklet' like this into the first line of your calculate function to indicate, that the function should run in the UI thread.